# Quantum $SU(2)$ and $3$-sphere

Tags: quantum-groups

There is a dipheomorphism of $SU(2)$ and $3$-sphere. What happens when you construct quantum $SU(2)$? Do we have an lifting of homeomorphism (or some other morphism) of quantum group to some other object -> quantized 3-sphere?